# Django custom user model: initial migration depends on migration for default auth app

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a new Django app, and moved over to a custom user model  provided by an app called `accounts` before creating any users or doing any actual work. This seemed to go fine- I've since created a couple users & customized the admin so that I can edit & create users from there.

I cloned my repo to another computer & ran into an error when attempting to start the dev server:

[image: secondary machine after trying to start dev server]

This makes sense, as I can't find any `auth` migrations in my project directory. However, when I create a new DB on my main dev machine & run `./manage.py migrate`, the output includes 8 migrations for the `auth` app:

[image: main dev machine after migrating new db]

On my secondary machine, I can comment out the dependency in the `accounts` initial migration, and things seem to work fine- the dev server starts, I can see the users added from my main dev machine (I'm using an sqlite3 DB for now), & use the Django admin however I need.

I figured that dependency might have been a leftover somehow, so I thought I might be able to remove the reference. However, if I comment out that dependency on my dev machine & attempt to migrate a new DB, I get an error.

I'm stumped here- where are these `auth` migrations if I have no actual migration files? Are they built-ins in `django.contrib.auth`?

*EDIT*: It appears the `auth` migrations are built in, so why can't my project access them when trying to start the dev server on my 2nd machine? I've tried specifically making migrations for the `auth` app to ensure they exist, but it reports no changes.

For reference, this is my `accounts` model & manager:

```
# accounts/models.py
"""
This model defines the custom user object
The main object of this user model is to use email as the
main unique field and remove username as a required field
"""

from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core import validators
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.manager import EmptyManager
from django.utils import six, timezone
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, username=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    A base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.
    Email and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('Email Address'), unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that email already exists."),
        }
    )
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    #app-specific user fields
    has_picked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        #abstract = True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    @property
    def display_name(self):
        """
        Returns first name and last initial, first name, or email prefix
        Depending on whats available
        """
        if self.first_name:
            if self.last_name:
                return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name[0] + '.'
            else:
                return self.first_name
        else:
            return self.email.split('@')[0]
```

And my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]
```

Comment: Yes, they are built in. Do you have the auth app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes I do. I should have included my INSTALLED_APPS in the question. Adding those now

Comment: so what is your question again?

Comment: I'm still unsure as to what's wrong with my project. I can't start the dev server on my 2nd machine unless the first migration of my `accounts` app has the dependency on `auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length` commented out. With `auth` in the installed apps, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration 0008 in the auth app was added in Django 1.10. You are presumably running an older version of Django on the other machine.

Comment: Shoot, thank you. That's exactly right- I knew my versions were different but it never crossed my mind that it could be the culprit. Thank you very much!